# Do endomorphisms of quotients always lift?

Tags: group-theory

Let $H \to G$ be an injective homomorphism of Abelian groups and let $\varphi$ be an endomorphism of $H$. Must $\varphi$ extend to an endomorphism of $G$? The answer is no; a counterexample is the endomorphism of the subgroup $2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ of $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ given by $(2,0) \to (0,1)$ and $(0,1) \to (0,0)$.

I am interested in the dual question. Let $G \to H$ be a surjective homomorphism of Abelian groups and let $\varphi$ be an endomorphism of $H$. Must $\varphi$ lift to an endomorphism of $G$?

I strongly suspect the answer to be no, but I have not been able to find a counterexample. An easy counterexample like the one above would be ideal, although any would be good. Note that if the map $G \to H$ splits then $\varphi$ must be induced by an endomorphism of $G$ (and similarly in the dual case). The two questions make sense for other objects also, and so if there is anything interesting to be said on this matter in categorical terms then I would be happy to hear it.

Comment: This is an instance of a problem that comes up in most first courses in representation theory: when do endomorphisms of a quotient module lift? The only really general thing one can say is that if the module you start with is projective, then every endomorphism of each quotient module lifts. As an application, the top of a projective indecomposable is simple, but in general the top of an indecomposable module might not be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the standard surjection $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

More specifically we have $$G=\langle x , y : x^4 = y^2 =1 , yx=xy\rangle \quad\text{and}\quad H=\langle \bar x, \bar y : \bar x^2 = \bar y^2 = 1, \bar y \bar x = \bar x \bar y \rangle$$

The elements of $G$ that have order 4 are $\{ x, xy, x^3, x^3y \}$, the elements that order 2 are $\{ y, x^2, x^2 y \}$, and the element of order 1 is just called $1$. The elements of $H$ are just $\{ \bar x, \bar y, \bar x \bar y \}$ of order 2, and $\bar 1$ of order 1.

An endomorphism of $G$ cannot take $y$ (of order 2) to any element of order 4. But the image in $H$ of the elements of $G$ order dividing 2 is only $\{ \bar 1 = \bar x^2, \bar y = \bar x^2 \bar y \}$. Hence an endomorphism of $H$ that is induced by an endomorphism of $G$ can only take $\bar y$ to $\bar y$ or $\bar 1$.

The endomorphisms of $H$ are most easily represented by $2\times 2$ matrices over $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. There are 16 such endomorphisms, but only 8 of them send $\bar y$ to $\bar y$ or $\bar 1$. The other 8 send $\bar y$ to $\bar x$ or $\bar x \bar y$. None of these latter 8 lift as shown in the previous paragraph. All of the former 8 do lift, though this doesn't matter very much.

In particular, 8 of the endomorphisms of $H$ lift (4 ways each), and 8 do not lift.

Comment: You could send $y$ to $x^2 y$ (which is of course congruent to $y$) as well. The point being, all the elements of order $2$ in the domain map to $0$ or $(0,1)$ in the target. (Also, +1)

Comment: Thank-you Jack, this is indeed a nice and simple example. I am also interested in whether there is any deeper (categorical) reason for this. For vector spaces both properties hold trivially, and for manifolds (i.e. a fibration) it might be more interesting (though surely standard for the right people). I'm happy to accept this as it answers what I asked.

Comment: You don't want $G$ to be a projective object in any category containing $G$, $H$, the quotient, and the endomorphisms involved. For instance we don't want $G$ cyclic. For the dual $H \leq G$, we don't want $G$ injective (so not finite cyclic, and not quasicyclic, or rank 1). I chose $G$ to have a more restricted structure than $H$. Quotients can simplify, so they can have more endomorphisms.

Comment: I was naively wondering if one could say that there is a functor common to these categories and it has a certain property for vector spaces but not for groups, or something along those lines. I'm sure you'd have mentioned that if it held any water. Thank-you Jack, for being helpful.

Comment: I don't think of End (the monoid of endomorphisms) as a functor (I mean it isn't one, but I don't try to fix this). The idea is if $H \leq G$ and $f:H \to H$ then we automatically get $f:H \to G$. Can we extend $f$ to $f:G \to G$? This is exactly the question: Is $\newcommand{\Hom}{\operatorname{Hom}}\Hom(G,G) \to \Hom(H,G)$ surjective? If $H=G/N$ and $f:H \to H$ then we automatically extend $f:G \to H:g\mapsto f(gN)$. But can we do $f:G \to G$? This is the question if $\Hom(G,G) \to \Hom(G,G/N)$ is surjective. $G$ such that $\Hom(G,X) \to \Hom(G,X/N)$ is surjective are called projective.

Comment: $G$ such that $\Hom(X,G) \to \Hom(Y,G)$ is surjective for $Y \leq X$ are called injective. So half of this is functor, and half of it is special property of $G$. There is actually some “quasi-injective” definition for $G$ with exactly the $H \leq G$ property you want. Let me know if you want it. Faith has written about it, but I never got into it.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations Jack. I found the definition of quasi-injective in the paper of Bertholf and Walls, and it is interesting. I won't get into it either though, as I have become a bit side-tracked with algebra lately and I've nearly forgotten what I was supposed to be doing :)